# Old windows 10 won't boot after clean install on new drive

Tags: windows, boot, bios

I had windows 10 installed on my drive which was fully working. I physically removed this had drive from my PC and installed a new hard drive. Then I installed windows 10 on the new drive, which works perfectly. Now I removed the new hard drive and connected the old one, and get a black screen instead of going into windows.

The drives had never been connected to the motherboard at the same time.

I use Asus motherboard. Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you have any other drives in your system?

Comment: Did you change anything like boot type or modes (AHCI/IDE or UEFI/Legacy) ?

Comment: Only the CD rom drive. I also disconnected it. No flash drives are attached too.

Comment: I tried to change from IDE to AHCI but it didn't help. I can't switch between UEFI/Legacy.